# How to encrypt sting with AES / CBC 128 with specific key and IV length

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, aes, password-encryption

I am trying to encrypt a string using AES cbc 128 but I got this problem every time

**self._cipher = factory.new(key, *args, kwargs)ValueError: IV must be 16 bytes long***

I am using pycrypto library and here is my code,

```
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

def pad(m):
     return m+chr(16-len(m)%16)*(16-len(m)%16)

msg = 'Hello there I am new in Python'
ciph = AES.new("asdfghjkl", AES.MODE_CBC, "asdfghjkl")
enc = ciph.encrypt(pad(msg))
base = base64.b64encode(enc)
print (base)
```

Whenever I change my key and IV length to 16 bit it worked ... but I want to encrypt the string only with this key and IV which is "**asdfghjkl**"

I have seen a lot of online websites that encrypt strings same way with any key , IV length .. but I did not figure it ... how does it work>

thanks in advance.

Comment: AES by definition uses a 16 bytes IV and key sizes of 16, 24 or 32 bytes. This cannot be changed.

Comment: That's exactly what I already answered: No, it's not possible, unless with cheating, as the linked site does. A simple test shows that for AES a too short key is silently extended to 16 bytes with 0x00 values, which is a bad handling of an invalid key, and is anything but a good example (like most online crypto sites).

Comment: A too short IV is extended in the same way.

Comment: @Topaco Note that AES doesn't use any IV, it is the mode of operation that does. AES/GCM would normally use a 12 byte IV. Also note that the IV **must** be unpredictable / randomized for AES-CBC, so extending the IV with zero's would be considered **insecure**. Mike211, the idea of encryption / decryption is to make data confidential. *Just getting it to work* should not be your goal. What these f*'ed up sites do is completely random and usually insecure. Don't confuse bits / bytes.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes - Well, this question is about AES/CBC and here the size of the IV is equal to the block size defined as 16 bytes for AES. Concerning security: I didn't go into this point at all, but thanks for the addition. Note that apart from the IV, a key extended with 0x00 values must also be considered insecure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well Mike as in the comments  AES uses a 16 bytes IV and 16, 24 or 32 bytes for the key size , so it is not possible to encrypt the Strings or whatever it was, with a short IV and Key unless u did some tricks for example extend the length with the value of Zeros until it becomes 16 Byte..

You can very simply convert ur password and IV to hex and add zeros until it becomes 16 in ur case the "**asdfghjkl**" will be in hex "**61 73 64 66 67 68 6a 6b 6c** " so u will need to add **00000000000000** this way it will work without any errors.. but it is not secure.. in python u can use unhexlify() to convert the hex key and iv to bytes.